# Use of uninitialized value error in concatenation

Tags: perl, input

From the code below, I get error

```
Use of uninitialized value $fileName in concatenation <.> or string at ... line 8.
```

I also get error

```
Can't open from: No such file or directory at ... line 8.
```

This is a sample code for homework reference. I am trying to comprehend it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dayLength = $ARGV[0];
my $byteLength = $ARGV[1];
my $fileName = $ARGV[2];

open INPUT, "< $fileName" or die "Can't open from: $!";
my $takeIn = <INPUT>;

print "$takeIn\n";

my @files = split / /, $takeIn;


print "@files\n";



foreach my $file (@files){
if(-M $file > $dayLength && -s $file > $byteLength){
print "\n::::::::$file::::::::\n";
open INPUT, "< $file" or die "Can't open from: $!";
my $i = <INPUT>;
while($i = <INPUT>){
print $i;}
    }}
```

Comment: Line 8 is the _first_ `open INPUT` line, are you sure this is the correct code?

Comment: In the slide it says the third argument is the name of the input file

Comment: When you run your program, are you passing it a third argument? If not, then that is why `$fileName` has no value.

Comment: how to run this programs?!?!

Answer (score 1):

As Hunter mentions, it appears that there is no third argument and $fileName is not set.

Try adding this before the call to open() to make sure the user provides a filename.

```
if (!defined($filename) or length($filename) == 0))
{
    die "filename argument is required";
}
```